# Adding line breaks with no word wrap css

Tags: css

I have a css class on a `textarea` like this..

```
.expanderHTMLText{
     font: 12px Arial, Helvetica;   
    min-height: 50px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

I do not want words to break in between long words, but I do want the text to fill the box not be all on 1 line with a scroll bar. I want to get rid of the horizontal scroll but not have to break the words to do it. How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: How about adding a `width` to the container where your text is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove white-space:nowrap; line and it will not be on one line.

Edit:
Who down-voted me? Please give me an explanation for that.

white-space: nowrap; explicitly defines, that wrapping will not occur. The only way how text can be wrapped is by removing or changing this property.
Default value for white-space property is normal, which acts almost identically to nowrap except it will wrap the text (collapse spaces).

If you do not want to words (even long ones) to be split on multiple lines, you will need to add word-wrap: normal; as JSW189 suggested.
But then you would still get a horizontal scrollbar if you would have a word which does not fit on one line - but thats obvious, you will either have word on multiple lines, either scrollbar.

Comment: I don't think this is what Nick is asking for. The question says: "I do want the text to fill the box ***not** be all on 1 line* with a scroll bar." The English is a bit uncelar, but I think he's saying he does not want all the text to be on one line. Using `white-space: nowrap` would make the text all on the same line. See: http://jsfiddle.net/QJqYQ/2/

Comment: Although perhaps Nick can clarify for us.

Comment: I dont want a horizontal scrollbar to show up but I also dont want the words to break

Comment: Yes, that's what I understood - he does not want text to be on one line, that's why I suggested removing of white-space: nowrap or setting white-space: normal.
And it depends on the browser, as the example you provided renders multiple lines on FF

Comment: @EvaldasDzimanavicius Oh sorry I misread your answer. My bad.

Comment: @NickLaMarca So you want long words to be clipped? If you don't want the words to break and you don't want a horizontal scrollbar, the words will either have to be clipped or the `textarea` would need to have a wider width.